# Is it possible to send a collection of ID's as a ADO.NET SQL parameter?

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net

Eg. can I write something like this code:

```
public void InactiveCustomers(IEnumerable<Guid> customerIDs)
{
    //...
    myAdoCommand.CommandText =
        "UPDATE Customer SET Active = 0 WHERE CustomerID in (@CustomerIDs)";
    myAdoCommand.Parameters["@CustomerIDs"].Value = customerIDs;
    //...
}
```

The only way I know is to Join my IEnumerable and then use string concatenation to build my SQL string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally the way that you do this is to pass in a comma-separated list of values, and within your stored procedure, parse the list out and insert it into a temp table, which you can then use for joins.  As of **Sql Server 2005**, this is standard practice for dealing with parameters that need to hold arrays.

Here's a good article on various ways to deal with this problem:

[Passing a list/array to an SQL Server stored procedure](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)

But for **Sql Server 2008**, we finally get to pass table variables into procedures, by first defining the table as a custom type.

There is a good description of this (and more 2008 features) in this article:

[Introduction to New T-SQL Programmability Features in SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270.aspx)

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html and http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html are the reference read on this topic. They also discuss the pros and cons in much more detail than the Vyas's one.

Comment: There is also a newer version of E. Sommarskog's articles for SQL Server 2008 (which focuses on Table-Valued Parameters): http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html. I think @RemusRusanu's comment deserves its own answer; I've posted such a one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31110710/240733

Answer (score 5):

You can with [SQL 2008](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/07/sql-server-2008-table-value-parameters.html).  It hasn't been out very long, but it is available.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter#comment1039858_114685), Erland Sommarskog wrote a series of articles on this topic (linked-to below). The articles are very thorough and can serve as reference material. While they are specific to SQL Server (T-SQL), some of the techniques mentioned might also work for other RDBMS (such as using an `XML` data type):

- **[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008 Using Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)**:

  - Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs)
- **[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond When TVPs Do Not Cut it](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)**:

  - string serialization and de-serialization of scalar values
  - SQLCLR
  - passing structured list data via the XML data type
  - Dynamic SQL
- **[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2000 and Earlier](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use xml parameter type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectByIdList(@productIds xml) AS

DECLARE @Products TABLE (ID int) 

INSERT INTO @Products (ID) SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @productIds.nodes('/Products/id') as ParamValues(ID) 

SELECT * FROM 
    Products
INNER JOIN 
    @Products p
ON    Products.ProductID = p.ID
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Nope. Parameters are like SQL values in obeying [first normal form](http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/sql/normal.htm), basically, there can only be one...

As you are probably aware, generating SQL strings is risky business: you leave yourself open to an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). As long as you're dealing with bona fide GUID's you should be fine, but otherwise you need to be sure to cleanse your input.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot pass a list as a single SQl Parameter. You could string.Join(',') the GUIDS  such as "0000-0000-0000-0000, 1111-1111-1111-1111" but this would be high on database overhead and sub-optimal really. And you have to pass the whole string as single concatenated dynamic statement, you can't add it as a parameter.

Question:

Where are you getting your list of ID's that represent inactive customers from?

My suggestion is to approach the problem a little differently. Move all that logic into the database, something like:

```
    Create procedure usp_DeactivateCustomers 
    @inactive varchar(50) /*or whatever values are required to identify inactive customers*/
    AS    
    UPDATE Customer SET c.Active = 0 
    FROM Customer c JOIN tableB b ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID 
    WHERE b.someField = @inactive
```

And call it as a stored procedure:

```
public void InactiveCustomers(string inactive)
{
    //...
    myAdoCommand.CommandText =
        "usp_DeactivateCustomers";
    myAdoCommand.Parameters["@inactive"].Value = inactive;
    //...
}
```

---

If a list of GUID's exist in a database, why do I need to: find them; put them in a generic list; unwind the list into a CSV/XML/Table variable, just to present them back to the DB again ????? They're already there! Am I missing something?

Comment: Downvoted because of the very first statement in your answer, which is not generally true. I agree with the suggestions towards the end of your question, though... in some cases, it *might* indeed be possible to do everything in the DB, so the problem of how to transfer lists might never arise at all.