# How to pass and Return a Array to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to pass an array to a stored procedure which in turn will return an array from c# .net?

Comment: How large is your array? (number of entries, and memory footprint)

Comment: .. and what DBMS are you using!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 4):

There are different options here depending on the scenario. I'm using SQL Server for a lot of the examples below, but much of it is broadly transferable between systems.

For a relatively small array (ideally vector) you can construct a delimited string (tab delimited, comma delimited, whatever), and pass that into your DB and parse - usually manually (DBMS often lack a "split" routine), but it is very easy to obtain a pre-written "split" implementation (for example, as a UDF in SQL Server). Typical usage:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM dbo.SplitUDF(@myarg) #udf
INNER JOIN SOME_TABLE st ON st.ID = #udf.Value
```

Xml is another option, especially for complex data; SQL Server 2005 and above has inbuilt xml parsing, but that should not be assumed in general.

[Table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) are another option, but this is SQL Server 2008 only - it might well be what you are looking for, though.

Another option, especially for large data, is to pump the data into the server *separately* (bulk insert, [`SQLBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), "bcp", SSIS whatever) and process the data via SQL once it is there.

To get array/tabular data out, a standard `SELECT` should be your default option, although you can of course also construct xml or delimited character data. The latter can be accomplished via a quirk of SQL:

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(max)
SET @foo = ''
SELECT @foo = @foo + st.SomeColumn + '|' -- pipe-delimited, note trailing |
FROM SOME_TABLE st
```