# How to implement a stored procedure for the following query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures, routines

I am having query as follows which will get multiple data at a time but I don't know how to write a stored procedure for this - can anyone help me?

In code I am writing this

```
string deleteSQL = "Select File_Data from tblachmaster WHERE Id IN (" + gvIDs.Substring(0, gvIDs.LastIndexOf(",")) + ")";
```

This instead of writing like this i have to use stored procedure to execute

This is my query

```
Select File_Data 
From tblachmaster 
Where Id IN (1,2,3, and so on);
```

Comment: This is in sql but might give a hint towards the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()    
BEGIN
 SELECT File_Data from tblachmaster WHERE Id IN (1,2,3, and so on);
END;
```

Comment: I did not want to hard code the values there i would like to pass them by declaring some variable

Comment: you must provide your that in your question then... =)