# SQL select with IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
declare @MenuIDs varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4';

SELECT 
    tMenuMain.MenuId, 
    tMenuMain.MenuRank 
INTO #TempRankTable 
FROM tMenuMain 
WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN (@MenuIDs);

select * from  #TempRankTable;
```

The @MenuIDs varaible is actually a sproc parameter. (I just declared it in the example to explain) 
How do I get the select to work, since the IN command only works with comma separated values and not just a string. Other problem I am facing is that tMenuMain.MenuId is an integer column. Is it possible to do a CAST in this situation?

Comment: definitely not easy! see [HERE](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). Do the menuIDs have to be in a comma seperated list like that? is there anyway you could put them into a single column table first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a little helper function that "maps" the string to a table;

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.str2ints(@str nvarchar(max))
RETURNS @ints TABLE (val INT)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml XML
  SET @xml = '<root><str>' + REPLACE(@str, ',', '</str><str>') + '</str></root>'
  INSERT INTO @ints(val)
  SELECT str.value('.', 'int') 
  FROM @xml.nodes('//str') AS RECORDS(str)
  RETURN
END
```

Then you can rewrite your function to use that function for splitting;

```
declare @MenuIDs varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4';

SELECT 
    tMenuMain.MenuId, 
    tMenuMain.MenuRank 
INTO #TempRankTable 
FROM tMenuMain 
WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.str2ints(@MenuIDs));

select * from  #TempRankTable;
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that the function is sorting the values?
If I pass '3,2,4,1' I get the results in the exact same order as when I pass '1,2,3,4'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic SQL and view:

```
declare @MenuIDs varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4';
declare @SQL varchar(max);

set @SQL = 'create view vTab as
            SELECT tMenuMain.MenuId, tMenuMain.MenuRank                 
            FROM tMenuMain 
            WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN ('+@MenuIDs+')';
/*
   Select in @SQL should look like:
            create view vTab as
            SELECT tMenuMain.MenuId, tMenuMain.MenuRank                 
            FROM tMenuMain 
            WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN (1,2,3,4)
*/

exec(@SQL)

select * 
into #TempRankTable 
from vTab 

drop view vTab   

select * from  #TempRankTable;
```

or if you can `create table` before insert

```
 declare @MenuIDs varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4';
 declare @SQL varchar(max);

 create table #TempRankTable 
 (
   MenuId ...
   MenuRank ...
 ) 

set @SQL = 'insert into #TempRankTable(MenuId,MenuRank) 
            SELECT tMenuMain.MenuId, tMenuMain.MenuRank                 
            FROM tMenuMain 
            WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN ('+@MenuIDs+')';
/*
   Select in @SQL should look like:
            insert into #TempRankTable(MenuId,MenuRank) 
            SELECT tMenuMain.MenuId, tMenuMain.MenuRank                 
            FROM tMenuMain 
            WHERE tMenuMain.MenuId IN (1,2,3,4)
*/

exec(@SQL)

select * from  #TempRankTable;
```

Comment: I've tried that before; I get this error:   
(4 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 17
Invalid object name '#TempRankTable'.

Comment: @Parado original answer would have been ok but it needed to create the temp table first `CREATE TABLE #TempRankTable (MenuId INT, MenuRank INT)` before the dynamic sql. and the `INSERT INTO` that table within the dynamic sql

Comment: It's true, but I think he doesn't want use `create table`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that works great, but is there a way I could avoid the INSERT INTO command?

Comment: You can use view, it's first example.

Answer (score 0):

There is easy and clean way to do what you want. The following question contains a lot of workarounds, using, for example, XML or a local function that splits the values:

- [Passing an array of parameters to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069311/87698)

An ugly but easy alternative would be to use the [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) method to verify if `',' + tMenuMain.MenuId + ','` is contained in `,1,2,3,4,` (note the starting and trailing commas).