# Passing an array of unique identifiers to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)
>   [Passing an array of parameters to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure)

I need to pass a collection of unique identifiers to my stored procedure. I wrote this query to test what I want to do:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   MyTable.TypeId IN ('852D7F39-302A-4E35-94D4-9A0335F8E9DC,1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82')
```

This query runs correctly. So I created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc] (
@TypeIdsList varchar(8000)
) AS

BEGIN
EXEC(
    'SELECT *
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE   MyTable.TypeId IN (' + @TypeIdsList + ')'
)
END
```

But when I execute it with some sample data:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[MySproc]
        @TypeIdsList = N'852D7F39-302A-4E35-94D4-9A0335F8E9DC,1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I get this error:

> *Incorrect syntax near 'D7F39'.*

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ids>
    <id value='852D7F39-302A-4E35-94D4-9A0335F8E9DC'/>
    <id value='1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82'/>
</ids>
```

```
create procedure [dbo].[MySproc] (@TypeIdsList xml)
as 
begin

    declare @idoc int
    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @TypeIdsList
    create table #ids (id uniqueidentifier)

    insert into #ids
            select a.value
                from openxml (@idoc, '/ids/id',1)
            with (value uniqueidentifier) a

    select t.*
        from MyTable t 
            inner join #ids i with (nolock) on t.TypeId = i.id     

-- or
-- SELECT t.*
-- FROM MyTable t
-- WHERE t.TypeId IN (SELECT i.id FROM #ids WITH(NOLOCK))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  What do you mean that your first query runs correctly?  To a human (at least this one), it would seem that you are looking for two values:  `'852D7F39-302A-4E35-94D4-9A0335F8E9DC'` or `'1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82'`.  However, SQL interprets your expression as *one* value, `'852D7F39-302A-4E35-94D4-9A0335F8E9DC,1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82'`, with a comma in it.

Your stored procedure seems to want to turn this into two values.  However, you have a problem with the commas.  You need something like:

```
WHERE   MyTable.TypeId IN (''' + replace(@TypeIdsList, ',', '''') + ''')'
```

Oh, that dynamic SQL can get confusing.  It might be easier just to use `charindex()` or `like` in regular SQL:

```
where charindex(','+MyTable.TypeId+',' , ','+@TypeIdsList+',') > 0
```

or

```
where ','+@TypeIdsList+',' like '%,'+MyTable.TypeId+',%'
```