# Stored procedure - Multiple string parameters with IN clause sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, in-clause

i want to filter the rows using Stored procedure. below is my query

```
   Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]      
   @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100)        
   AS      
   BEGIN     

        Select * from master where name in (@SearchTerm)

   END
```

In code behind,

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", "peter")
```

when i run with above parameter, it's work fine.

but when i pass like this
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", "'peter','rahul'")

this time no rows fetching.

i tried manually then also it's not working.

```
    exec Test ''peter','rahul''
```

Please help me, how to pass muliple string Using IN clause?

Comment: Passing array of values into the SP is not that easy. See this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure) with a couple of options.

Comment: yea, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069388/223752 solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

One method is

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]      
   @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100)        
   AS      
    BEGIN     
      Select * from master where ','+@SearchTerm+',' like '%,'+name+',%'
```

You can find more methods at http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html