# How to pass value to the data-table in the stored procedure while executing in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes 2 parameters of UDT.

How can I pass the value to the stored proc parameters while executing this stored procedure?

For ex:

```
create  procedure temp
(
   @input1 AS Datatable1 READONLY, 
   @input2 AS Datateble2 READONLY,
)
```

Here `Datatable1` and `Datatable2` are table types

So how can I execute the procedure?

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: See: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters

Comment: Check Panagiotis Kanavos's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541079/pass-list-of-strings-to-a-stored-procedure/28541212#28541212

Comment: check  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911789/passing-parameter-of-list-of-values-and-tables-to-stored-procedure/23931148#23931148

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @p1 DataTable1;
DECLARE @p2 DataTable2;

INSERT @p1 VALUES (...);
INSERT @p2 VALUES (...);

EXEC temp @input1= @p1, @input2= @p2;
```

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, could you clarify why?  You're asking how to pass table valued parameters and execute a stored procedure - this is how you do it.  Without column information on the table types I can't provide any more details about what the insert should look like.

Comment: No problem.  If it answered your question, please consider accepting it as the answer.  I still don't know why it got voted down, this is really the easiest and most straightforward way to use TVPs in SQL....