# How to pass an array to sql?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm beginner in sql.
I want that deleteseveral rows from my table Once (no One to One). I think that the best way is use array.
I want pass Id of rows (of type int) to store procedure with array. I search and find several way. but don't find my sulotion yet.
I Thanks any one that guide me. :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a link that I found useful. it solve my problem.
I hope that it helpful for you,too :)
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631284/How-to-pass-an-array-to-SQL-SERVER-stored-pro

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. :) Follow the next steps,

1. Open the Query Designer
2. Copy Paste the Following code as it is,it will create the Function which convert the String to Int

   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
   (
      @List      VARCHAR(MAX),
      @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)
   )
   RETURNS TABLE
   AS
     RETURN ( SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM
         ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
           FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '*'
           + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '**') + '*').query('.')
             ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
         WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
     );
   GO
3. Create the Following stored procedure

   ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DeleteMultipleId
    @List VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         DELETE FROM TableName WHERE Id IN( SELECT Id = Item FROM dbo.SplitInts(@List, ',')); 
    END
    GO
   ```
4. Execute this SP Using `exec sp_DeleteId '1,2,3,12'` this is a string of Id's which you want to delete,
5. You convert your array to string in C# and pass it as a Stored Procedure parameter

int[] intarray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] result = intarray.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "sp_DeleteMultipleId";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.VARCHAR).Value=result ;
```

This will delete multiple rows, All the best

Comment: In your solution how to pass array to store procedure.my id is int type. I saw this link before. but I have problem yet.

Comment: Do you want to pass array to stored procedure from Code Behind?

Comment: Can you explain about dbo.SplitInts? I pass value from code behind with string. not string[]. also i change id types from int to double.

Comment: You can use your logic to convert the int array to single string seperated by comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMl datatype,to pass Int Array list.
Bind your ID list in XML object.Pass it to SP. And in SP , Take Node from XML parameter.
You can refere below link.

[Passing an array of parameters to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

If your Id's array start from 1 and end to 10 You can use the following code in store Procedure

If your Id's array start from 1 and end to 10 You can use the following code in store Procedure

```
AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @Count NUMERIC(18,0)
  SET @Count = 1
       WHILE(@Count <= 10 )
       BEGIN
           DELETE FROM TableName WHERE Id=@Count
           SET @Count=@Count+1
       END
    END    
END
```

Comment: No, Ids are different value any time!