# SQL SELECT Arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, t-sql, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to send a collection of ID’s as a ADO.NET SQL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter)

**Duplicate:** this is a duplicate of [Is it possible to send a collection of ID’s as a ADO.NET SQL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter) and many others. Please vote to close it and add any additional answers to one of the other duplicates.

Given an array of parameters, I want to write a SELECT/WHERE/IN statement that can handle it. I would have thought I could do something like this.

```
// Given List<int> listOfLanguageIDs...
string cmdText =
    "SELECT StringID\n" +
    "FROM TRANSLATIONTB\n" +
    "WHERE LanguageID IN(@arrayOfLanguagesIDs)";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, ConnectionManager.Connection))
{                       
    command.Parameters.Add( "arrayOfLanguagesIDs", SqlDbType.IntArray ).Value = listOfLanguageIDs.ToArray();

...
```

But alas, this does not seem to be the case, and my searching hasn't turned up anything. Am I asking the wrong questions? Or does everyone really write their own array builder/SqlDbType converter/etc?

Comment: This is a major duplicate. It should have its own FAQ. Consider not answering for a few minutes while I find some of the duplicates.

Comment: Ok, that didn't take long: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Its more like:

```
create  proc [dbo].[GetRequestsItems](@RequestIds as varchar(8000)) as
exec('select ri.id, ri.RequestID, ri.Namefrom RequestItems ri with(nolock)
where RequestID in ('+@RequestIds+')')
```

and then you pass in a string of ids like: "3, 47, 10, 9"

Comment: And get all the wonders of SQL injection.

Comment: I don't think you are going to have an input box where the user types in a bunch of ids.  My example came from a list that the user could check the checkboxes of the rows they wanted, I then generate the list of IDs based on that.  Then bring back the child rows. No opportunity for sql injection there.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) by Erland Sommarskog. The reference article on the subject, with all alternatives deeply covered and discussed. The SO duplicate actually fails to mention this one, which is a shame.

As of 2008 there is also the [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) option.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it useful to use stored procedures with the array of values passed in as XML:

```
<languages>
   <id>2001</id>
   <id>2023</id>
   <id>2076</id>
</languages>


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStringsFromLanguageIds]
@languageIds xml
AS
BEGIN

SELECT StringID
FROM TRANSLATIONTB
JOIN @languageIds.nodes('languages/id') R(languages)
ON LanguageID = languages.value('.','int')

END
```

Comment: @James: just curious. Your choice either way, but did you read the part about how this question is likely to be closed as a duplicate?