# SQL stored procedure taking 2 arrays and 1 int ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query filtering by list of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561465/sql-query-filtering-by-list-of-parameters)

I have a method ADO.NET that passes an array of strings, a name, and an array of ints to a stored procedure. I can do that one at a time but I want to pass them along all at once .. is it possible?

Using SQL server 2008

Thanks

Comment: What's RDBMS are you using? I believe only a select few have the concept of arrays.

Comment: [Possible Duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561465/sql-query-filtering-by-list-of-parameters#comment15293226_11561465)

Comment: Can you show some sample values, indicate how the individual elements in the array are related (e.g. is the first name related to the first int, or are they completely unrelated sets), and what the stored procedure should do with them?

Comment: Alright, I have to create a stored procedures that inserts data into 2 tables. 1. Fruit and second to FruitType .. Fruit has an ID (auto generated PK), the string ARRAY of information as FuritInfo .. the FruitType has ID which is the same as in fruit as it is PK and FK, and FruitTypeID as FK and PK and Fruit information array.. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a Table Parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Basically, you can construct a C# DataTable, and populate all the values in it, and then provide the table as a parameter to a SQL Stored procedure.

Unfortunately, without a bit more information, I can't propose sample code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array, you can send them as comma separated(and hence making them as a single string) and use it according.