# Stored Procedure Confusion

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am trying to create a stored procedure which will check for a list names in a table and there corresponding (boolean/bit) values, even if one of record has value as true, stored procedure should return True, if not then return false.

Here's the table,

```
Table Name - FruitCrate
Column A (VarChar (Max)) - FruitName
Column B (bit)  -  Eatable
```

Now I want a stored procedure whom I can provide a List FruitNames and it checks if any of them is eatable then return true otherwise false.

**Not sure how to get started as never sent list as parameter to stored procedure.**

**Edit**

This is what I am trying but getting syntax error,

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
(
    @FruitNames varchar(max)
)
AS

Select * From    
(SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ '))

WHERE FruitCrate.Eatable= 1
```

**Error**
**

> ... Incorrect syntax near ')'.... Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WHERE'.

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: You can send your fruitNames as a comma separated (or any other delimiter which is not in any fruit names, ex `'!'` or `'|'`) string

**Step 2**: You need a Table Valued T-Sql Function to split a delimited string ([Such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)) (say, table column name is `myColumn`)

```
CREATE FUNCTION  Split (@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (myColumn nvarchar(500))
AS
BEGIN

    --Function body
    RETURN @Results
END
```

**Step 3**: Write a stored procedure to compare splitted fruitenames with the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEatables
   @fruitName nVarchar(4000) --Change the length as required
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FruitName, COALESCE(Eatable,0) Eatable
    FROM FruitCrate fc JOIN dbo.Split(@fruitNames,',') fn
                   ON fc.FruitName = fn.myColumn
END
```

Comment: thanks, is it a Scalar function or table valued function, I am going to try it now

Comment: You need a `Table Valued Function`.

Comment: I didn't tried it, as I am going to change my approach, but will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter), which uses a comma separated list of ID.

You will have same implementation in your stored procedure