# What's wrong with this SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In reference to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695466/stored-procedure-confusion#18695836) I am trying this select statement and getting error

```
Select * From    
(SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ '))

WHERE FruitCrate.Eatable= 1
```

Error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

**Edit**

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPName]
(
    @FruitNames
)
AS

exec('SELECT  *  
    FROM FruitCrate
    WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')
    and Eatable = 1')
```

Comment: I will be using Strongly Typed Dataset with this stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a comma seperated string to the `in` operator. And you need just 1 query if you use  `and` for the conditions.

```
exec('SELECT * 
      FROM FruitCrate 
      WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')
      and FruitCrate.Eatable= 1'
```

If you want to execute a dynamic query (which is the case here)  that you have to use  `exec`

Comment: thanks, I am trying to create a stored procedure which will get list as parameter, so @FruitNames is a list of strings seperated by ";"

Comment: If you use `,` instead of `;` my query above will work. Otherwise you have to replace `;` with `,`

Comment: But there's a problem, I need it to be in SP and exec can't used in SP if I am right

Comment: I tried and getting this error, Must declare the scalar variable "@FruitNames".

Comment: Please add your stored procedure header code to your question. You need an input parameter for your stored procedure that is named `@FruitNames`. The error says: *I don't have a variable named `@FruitNames`

Comment: you are missing the data type of your input parameter. Example `@FruitNames varchar(1000)`

Answer (score 2):

You should name your subquery as below

```
Select * From    
(SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')) tab    
WHERE tab.Eatable= 1
```

and you shoud use the code as dynamic sql

```
exec('Select * From    
    (SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')) tab    
    WHERE tab.Eatable= 1')
```

it will work for list like `'apple','strawberry','banana'`

```
Select * From    
(SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN ('apple','strawberry','banana')) tab    
WHERE tab.Eatable= 1
```

Comment: Although correct, I'm pretty sure this is not what op is trying to achieve.

Comment: The `in` operator will not work with 1 string containing a list.

Comment: @Vatev if the names looks like `'apple','strawberry','banana'`  ?

Comment: If they are also properly escaped... I'm not familiar with sql-server, and I don't know if its easy to escape strings there.

Comment: @Vatev We don't know that, op's should describe it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select * From    
(SELECT * FROM FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')) as FruitCrateRes
WHERE FruitCrateRes.Eatable= 1
```

You have used table name FruitCrate without rename of subquery input of your from clause

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using

```
SELECT * FROM  FruitCrate WHERE FruitName IN (' +@FruitNames+ ')
WHERE FruitCrate.Eatable= 1
```

Probably, using your sub query, SQL engine doesn't recognize `FruitCrate` in last `WHERE`, because subquery name was not specified.

Your `IN` clause may be misused, also!